# Apache Kafka and durable subscribtion

Tags: apache-kafka, integration, messaging, producer-consumer

I'm considering using Apache Kafka and I could not find any information about durable subscriptions. Let's say I have expiration of 5 seconds for messages in my partition. Now if consumer fails and reconnects after 5 seconds, the message he missed will be gone. Even worse, he wont know that he missed a message. The durable subscription pattern solves this by saving the message for the consumer that failed or was disconnected. Is similar feature implemented in Kafka?

Comment: What you're describing sounds more like "not having an expiration".

Comment: It effectivley is, but just for some consumers. I need to know if such thing is supperted by Kafka as my use case requires quite tight expiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by Kafka. But you can of course always increase your retention time, and thus limit the probability that a consumer misses messages.

Furthermore, if you set `auto.offset.reset` to `none` you will get an exception that informs you if a consumer misses any messages. Hence, it is possible to get informed if this happens.

Last but not least, it might be possible, to use a `compacted` topic -- this would ensure, that messages are not deleted until you explicitly write a so-called tombstone message. Note, that records must have unique keys to use a compacted topic.